# Open a terminal from the current terminal and run a command in the new terminal

Tags: command-line

I'm relatively new to Linux and all of these helpful community forums. I was curious about running a command from a terminal that would open another terminal and run the proceeding command without switching. I'm not sure how clear that sounds, what I'm trying to do is run

```
avahi-daemon  avahi-browse -a -t
```

but as you can tell `avahi-browse -a -t` would need to be run in a new terminal. How can I run this line of code in one terminal and have it run the code automatically in a new terminal?

```
gnome-terminal
```

is there even a work around to force a command into a terminal?

update:

```
 avahi-daemon && gnome-terminal -x sh -c avahi-browse -a -t


Option “-x” is deprecated and might be removed in a later version of gnome-terminal.

Option “-e” is deprecated and might be removed in a later version of gnome-terminal.

 Use “-- ” to terminate the options and put the command line to execute after it
```

nothing happens with

```
 avahi-daemon && gnome-terminal -- sh -c avahi-browse -a -t
```

Comment: What's your Ubuntu release and `gnome-terminal` version (see the output of `lsb_release -c` and `gnome-terminal --version` respectively)? If the developers changed the command-line syntax, we'd need to know the version when that happened so we can add or amend an answer with an accurate solution for those newer versions.

Comment: I wish i could help with my gnome terminal version, but after trying to run these commands my terminal does pop up but the screen is completely blank now, i don't believe i did anything to bash at all